Change font size of text inside HTML() in Shiny
I have an HTML() object similar to this in my Shiny app, to generate a bullet point list:
text <- HTML(
    "
    <h1>Title</h1>
    Some text goes here
    <br/>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <h3>Another title</h3>
    Some text goes here
    </li>
    <li>
    Some other text goes here
    </li>
    </ul>
    "
)


How do I change the font sizes of the elements in the HTML()? Alternatively, is there a better way to generate a bullet point list?

My approach :

use markdown to prepare the content
use html to generate the output

below is the code:
library(shiny)
markdown('# head1 \n## head2\n- list1 \n- list2 ') |> HTML()


head1 head2  list1 list2 

